# How to add multiple CIDR block for a VPC using FindinMap Function - AWS CF

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a YAML Script with AWS CF deployment.
I have Mappings given with multiple CIDR Blocks and need to add multiple CIDR Blocks for a VPC creation with Function FindinMap
Here is my code:

```
Mappings:
  VPCaddressPrefix:
    values:
      voice1Octet: '10.0.0.0/22'
      voice2Octet: '10.3.8.0/23'
      voice3Octet: '10.7.12.0/24'

  Vpc:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock:
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice1Octet ]
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice2Octet]
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice3Octet ]
```

I am getting error as "Properties validation failed for resource Vpc with message:

> **#/CidrBlock: expected type: String, found: JSONArray"**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/APVcD.png)

Like to know how to resolve this using Mapping and FindinMap Function. Any Workaround ?

Tried :

```
Vpc:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock:
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice1Octet ]
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice2Octet]
        - !FindInMap [ VPCaddressPrefix,values,voice3Octet ]
```

Need three CIDR blocks for a VPC using FindinMap Function

Answer (score 0):

CidrBlock on [AWS::EC2::VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html) is a string representing a single CIDR block. It cannot be a list of CIDR blocks, as you're trying to use.

The way to do this is with [AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpccidrblock.html), for example create the base VPC with the voice1Octet CIDR and then associate the additional 2 CIDRs via multiple AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock resources.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: >
  StackOverflow 77835964

Mappings:
  VPCaddressPrefix:
    values:
      voice1Octet: 10.0.0.0/22
      voice2Octet: 10.3.8.0/23
      voice3Octet: 10.7.12.0/24

Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [VPCaddressPrefix, values, voice1Octet]

  cidr2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [VPCaddressPrefix, values, voice2Octet]

  cidr3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap [VPCaddressPrefix, values, voice3Octet]
```